# aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-i’

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, compiler-errors, preprocessor

I use this command->

```
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -i ok.c
```

to see the output of the prepossesses file

But it gives me error->

```
    aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-i’
```

I use both native and cross compiler(gcc and aarch64-linux-gnu) but both produces same result,  the --help command show where there is no -i command at any compiler,

I find this command in "Advanced C and C++ Compiling - 2014 by Milan Stevanovic" book.

My os is Ubuntu - 20.04.2 LTS

Compiler version : gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0  and

aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Comment: What exactly does the book say? I'm not sure what you want here.

Comment: Who told you to use the `-i` argument? The book? Do the book use GCC as well or some other compiler?

Comment: The command in compiling preprocessing example.. The book say " The gcc compiler provides the mode in which only the preprocessing stage is performed on the input source files:
gcc -i <input file> -o <output preprocessed file>.i
Unless specified otherwise, the output of the preprocessor is the file that has the same name as the input file and
whose file extension is .i. The result of running the preprocessor on the file function.c looks like that in Listing 2-4."

Comment: The standard GCC option to only run the preprocessor have always been `-E`.

Comment: Thank you so much .... Now it works completely

Comment: I have found reviews that say the book have some errors, but haven't found an errata to fix those errors. This is probably one of the errors.